# Get the selected items of a ListView (MVVM, Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, caliburn.micro

**What is the situation:**

I'm working on a C# WPF application with Caliburn.Micro. I am using the MVVM pattern.

I have a ListView with a ContentControl as ItemTemplate. The ListView's ItemsSource is bound to a List (ObservableCollection) of ViewModels in the corresponding ViewModel.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelList}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

---

**What I want:**

I want to get the selected items (all of them) of the ListView, but I don't know how without violating the MVVM pattern.

It would be nice to have a property "IsSelected" in the ViewModels that are presented by the ContentControl and to bind that somehow to my ListView.

Is it possible to do that or is there another/a better way?

---

**Update:**

It was easier than expected. I added a property `public bool IsSelected { get; set; }` in my ViewModel and put this inside the ListView Control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now I can get the selected items with:

```
foreach (var item in ViewModelList)
{
     if (item.IsSelected)
     {
          // Do stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: Looks like ListViewItem has IsSelected Property.  Create a Property to bind in the view model composing your viewModel list.

Comment: On sees such answers everywhere, but it seems to no longer work in WPF 4 (StaticResource not found). I removed the 'BasedOn' part and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the code you're looking for. If you're using a multiple selection list view, you could get all the selected items with below code.

`xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=ListViewName}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Bind it to a command in the viewmodel.

```
    private ICommand selectionChanged;
    public ICommand SelectionChanged
    {
        get { return selectionChanged; }
        set { SetProperty(ref selectionChanged, value); }
    }
```